# Go: comparing anonymous structs

Tags: go

I don't understand how `go` compares anonymous structures. I am trying to understand this piece of code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type foo struct {
    bar string
}

func main() {
    var x struct {
        bar string
    }
    var y foo
    fmt.Println(x == y) // this prints true
    equals(x, y) // this prints false

}


func equals(a, b interface{}) {
    fmt.Println(a == b)
}
```

Why does `x == y` yields `true`? They have a different type, so I would expect that they cannot be compared.

And, as they are equal, why casting them to `interface{}` makes them unequal?

Answer (score 6):

> Why does x == y yields true?

From the [Go language specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators):

> Struct values are comparable if all their fields are comparable. Two struct values are equal if their corresponding non-blank fields are equal.

The zero-value for a `string` is `""`, so `x.bar` and `y.bar` are equal, and therefore `x` and `y` are equal.

---

> why casting them to interface{} makes them unequal?

Again, from the same page in the language specification:

> Interface values are comparable. Two interface values are equal if they have identical dynamic types and equal dynamic values or if both have value nil.

Comment: You can also add these three quotes from the spec to explain why the two anonymous structs can be compared: "In any comparison, the first operand must be assignable to the type of the second operand", "A value x is assignable to a variable of type T ("x is assignable to T") in any of these cases:

x's type is identical to T.", "Two struct types are identical if they have the same sequence of fields, and if corresponding fields have the same names, and identical types, and identical tags."

Answer (score 2):

They have a different type but are comparable since the structs have the same field names/types.  If you try renaming the field, it won't compile.

They are comparable as interface{} values, but their dynamic types are different - You can check this with the fmt `%T` verb

http://play.golang.org/p/x0w30RIb5a